# I am using multiple commands as a query but i could not understand where to add braces in the query

Tags: mysql, subquery

Let  be the number of CITY entries in STATION, and let  be the number of distinct CITY names in STATION; query the value of  from STATION. In other words, find the difference between the total number of CITY entries in the table and the number of distinct CITY entries in the table.
[Table:STATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVXNu.png)

```
SELECT  ((SELECT (COUNT (CITY) FROM STATION))-(SELECT (COUNT DISTINCT (CITY)FROM STATION)));
```

I dont understand the correct way to add braces in the query.

Comment: `select count(city) - count(distinct city) from station`is just enough

Comment: what you have used inside braces are called subqueries and they are not needed is this context http://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php

Comment: plz explain this with some tables structure